# Connect with Oracle Database via LDAP Authentication

Tags: python, oracle11g, ldap, database-connection, cx-oracle

I am using python's pyodbc library to connect with the Oracle Database. The authentication to my non-prod servers were set-up as ***Basic Authentication*** so my connection string worked well.

It was tough to understand and set up the right drivers initially, But then did manage to get through. Here is what the code looks like for connection and worked well for my other servers.

```
import textwrap
import pyodbc
connection_string = textwrap.dedent('''Driver={driver};
            DBQ={hostname}:{port}/{sid};
            UID={username};
            PWD={password};
            Connection Timeout=30;
            Trusted_Connection="yes"
        '''.format(driver = 'Oracle in instantclient_11_2', 
                    hostname = <hostname>, 
                    port = <port>,
                    sid = <sid>,
                    username = <username>,
                    password = <passwd>
                    ))

connection = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
```

To my surprise PROD is authenticated via LDAP only. To which I have the *LDAP Server, Context, and DB Service* along with the credentials.

I tried creating my connection string as

```
connection_string = textwrap.dedent('''Driver={driver};
            DBQ={hostname}:{port}/{sid};
            UID={username};
            PWD={password};
            Connection Timeout=30;
            Authentication=LDAP;
            Trusted_Connection="yes"
        '''.format(driver = 'Oracle in instantclient_11_2', 
                    hostname = <ldap_server>, 
                    port = 389,
                    sid = <db_service>,
                    username = <username>,
                    password = <passwd>
                    ))
```

To which I was not surprised to know it wont work. Tried going through many links but could not get through. Has anyone tried this before or please let me know what I must be missing.

I could definitely connect in SQL Developer using the LDAP Authentication. And since TNS Listener is not configured on this server I cannot use Basic Authentication to connect.

And help would be welcome on this.

Comment: I have added my answer below to the above question.

Answer (score 0):

**Setting up Oracle Drivers -**  *(This is a pre-requisite if exist please ignore)*

1. Download Oracle Instant Client for Microsoft Windows (x64) 64-bit. Alternatively download available for your 32 bit system.
2. Choose your version of Oracle Database. My version was 11.2.0.4.0
3. Download below files -
   i. Instant Client Package - Basic
   ii. Instant Client Package - ODBC
4. Unzip both the packages into the same directory such as C:\oracle\instantclient_19_3.
5. Execute odbc_install.exe from the Instant Client directory. If Instant Client is 11g or lower, start the command prompt with the Administrator privilege.
6. Create `C:\oracle\instantclient_19_3\network\admin` folder to place tnsnames.ora, sqlnet.ora.
7. Set Environment variable - TNS_ADMIN to above folder location.
8. Add `C:\oracle\instantclient_19_3` to `PATH` Environment variable.
9. Add `C:\oracle\instantclient_19_3` to `ORACLE_HOME` (optional, if connection doesn't work try this.)

**LDAP Authentication**

1. Create two files: `sqlnet.ora` and `ldap.ora`

```
ldap.ora
```

```
# Place this file in the network/admin subdirectory or your 
# $ORACLE_HOME location.
# LDAP Server name should be added here. Rest all the values remains unchanged.
DIRECTORY_SERVERS = (your-server.your-organization:389:636)    
DEFAULT_ADMIN_CONTEXT = "ldap-ou-designation"
DIRECTORY_SERVER_TYPE = OID
```

```
sqlnet.ora
```

```
# Place this file in the network/admin subdirectory or your 
# $ORACLE_HOME location.
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES=(NTS)
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH = (LDAP)
```

2. Verify `C:\oracle\instantclient_19_3` is present in the Path else try updating the path in the Python Code as below

```
import os
lib_dir=r"C:\oracle\instantclient_19_3"
os.environ["PATH"] = lib_dir + ";" + os.environ["PATH"]
```

3. With all this set-up in place you should have
   username, password and DB Service name lets call it as db_service here

**with cx_Oracle**

```
import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect('{0}/{1}@{2}'.format(user, password, db_service))

version_script = "SELECT * FROM v$version"
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute(version_script)
version = cursor.fetchall()
print(version[0][0])

Ouput
-----
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
```

**with pyodbc**

```
import pyodbc
con = pyodbc.connect('Driver={0};DBQ={1};UID={2};PWD={3}'.format(driver, db_service, user, password))

version_script = "SELECT * FROM v$version"
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute(version_script)
version = cursor.fetchall()
print(version[0][0])

Ouput
-----
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
```

```
#Drivers for pyodbc 
pyodbc.drivers()

Output
------
['ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
 'Oracle in instantclient_11_2']
```

**References :**

https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html
https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/releasenote-odbc-ic.html
https://eikonomega.medium.com/connecting-to-oracle-database-with-cx-oracle-and-ldap-5da7925a305c